# MacBookPro display issue when booting via USB stick to live mode

Tags: 13.10, display, macbook-pro

Greetings Ubuntu community.

I'm currently trying to set up Ubuntu 13.10 on my MacBookPro11,2. I'm trying to follow the instructions outlined on the [MacBookPro11-1/Saucy page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro11-1/Saucy). I downloaded the NON-MAC 64-bit iso (ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso) and used unetbootin to create the bootable USB stick. I also tried an alternative method described [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx). Both stick drive creation methods allowed me to boot to live mode via USB, but the resulting experience is not easy on the eyes. It appears as vertical pastel stripes that are a few pixels wide. [Here is a photo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5nEK8x2blSeWU1SGZtaGtOU29vdmpXYVBxbkprc0JXREVn/edit?usp=sharing) I took of the display. I tried adjusting the resolution, but it just changes the width of the crazy stripes. I can't stand to look at it for more than a few seconds at a time. Let me know if you have any idea what the issue may be.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out the reason for the issue, and yes, I was able to reproduce it with my friend's Macbook as well. Yet I couldn't find any explanation online.

As a workaround, I plugged in an external monitor to be able to view the desktop and get through the install steps. Once the installation succeeded, I updated grub per instructions in the document linked above. After rebooting to the installed Ubuntu, the psychedelic glitch did not reoccur.

(Since I ran the installation with the "Update from the internet" feature enabled, I'm suspecting that some video driver patch was applied during installation.)